# Why the search bar's display is difference between IOS and Android in website?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I design a site with wordpress and I have a problem in some cases in mobile display. For example in IOS in the search bar, content doesn't display complete but in Android is OK !

this is the android screenshot :

[image: a android screenshot]

and this is the IOS screenshot :

[image: a IOS screenshot]

How to fix this ?

this is my site :  [matiloos.com](https://matiloos.com/)

Comment: It's a responsive design issue. please provide html and css of search bar for detecting problem.

Comment: tanx for edit .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference was in the browsers. iphone use safari browser and for responsive website in iphone We should check in safari windows.

For this problem I set height for input element and problem solved.